# You have $ 12$ different toys and $4$ children. If each child is to receive $3$ toys then how many different ways can this be done?

Tags: combinatorics

Stars and Bars question:

> You have $12$ different toys and $4$ children. If each child is to receive $3$ toys then how many different ways can this be done?

I know you could do

$$\binom{12}{3}\times\binom{9}{3}\times\binom{6}{3}\times\binom{3}{3}$$

but how about using the stars and bars method?
I got:

$$3a+3b+3c+3d=12$$

$$a+b+c+d = 4$$

By Stars and Bars, we get:
$$\binom{4+4-1}{4} = \binom{7}{4}$$

Though the answer I got above is not the same as $\binom{7}{4}$... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your first answer is correct.  It's not clear what your stars and bars method is.  What are $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: the four children...

Comment: no, $a,b,c,d$ are numbers.  How can you add children together to get the number 4?

Comment: each child gets 3 books, 3(a+b+c+d)=12 => a+b+c+d=4

Comment: I understand that you have four variables, each relating to one of the children.  But I'm asking what they represent.  The number of toys that each receives?  But that doesn't make sense since we're told they each receive 3.  So I'm having trouble understanding what those variables represent.

Comment: the letters represent children.

Comment: In the stars and bars methods, the stars are all identical. It's the bars (or boxes) that are distinct. In this case, the stars (toys) are all distinct, as you mentioned. That's what is incorrect with the second answer. As mentioned by @norfair, your 1st answer is correct.

Comment: So my answer would be correct if they *weren't* distinct?

Comment: @DevAllanPer no, your second answer is incorrect even if they are not distinct. You have already said that everyone must get 3 toys. Suppose the no of toys 1st child gets are a, 2nd b, 3rd c, 4th d. So, a+b+c+d=12. But, you've already given that a=b=c=d=3. So, there's only one solution. You can see this intuitively too. All the toys are the same. No matter which kid gets which toy first, ultimately all of them are gonna get 3 toys, all same => 1 way. Hope it helps ;)

Comment: @ Ankit Kumar The question said "You have 12 different toys", not all the same as you posted in your comment.

Comment: @poetasis I've written two comments. One for distinct and one for same toys.

Answer (score 1):

The stars and bars works like this:

I have $n$ things (toys) and I want to put them in $m$ buckets (children). I want know how many ways there are of putting the $n$ things in the $m$ buckets.

With this, we have $n$ stars and $m-1$ bars. And the formula is $\frac{(n + m-1)!}{(n! (m-1)! )}$

The bars and stars method doesn't work in your problem because you have a restriction to assign $3$ toys to every children.